# MDI Form from OnClientConnect static method

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing client server app and my server is WinForm.
i am trying to create child form from static method like that

```
private static void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    try
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);

        clientSocket = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyn);
        clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = 1024;
        frmClient frmClient = new frmClient(clientSocket);
        frmClient.Show(this);               

    }
    catch (Exception se)
    {
        throw;
    }

    WaitForClientConnect();
}
```

but "**this**" is not accepted because i am using it inside static method.

i also tried to create static field holding this and use it.
but also throw cross threads exception.

any suggestions.?

Comment: `this` refers to the instantiated object in the current context. If you're in a static context, there's no current object. Therefore it will never work. Why does the method need to be static?

Comment: Just as a note, your `catch` block is quite pointless.

Comment: method needs to be static because it is used in AsyncCallback like that {_listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new System.AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), obj);}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the MDI parent window in a static variable like

```
public static Form RootForm;
```

Then you can show a new MDI child, taking cross-threading into account like this.

```
public static void ShowFormForClient(TcpClient clientSocket) {
  // check if we are on a different thread and redirect if so
  if (RootForm.InvokeRequired) {
     RootForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { ShowFormForClient(clientSocket); });
     return;
  }
  var frmClient = new frmClient(clientSocket);
  frmClient.MdiParent = RootForm;
  frmClient.Show();
}
```

Note that this code is not tested in any ways, only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: how to create that delegate for ShowFormForClient

Comment: Just put it into your class where you define your MDI container, or anywhere else. You can put it wherever you want, because it's static too. You just need to be able to reference your static MDI container instance.

Comment: it says can't convert lambada expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not delegate

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the code, now it should compile and work.

Comment: thanks for your support , but now when instantiating more than one form of frmClient, the methods inside frmClient class sometimes executed only in the first instance!! any idea?

Comment: I have no idea, but I guess it's not related to this technique. I could help if I could see your whole code, but it's not possible in the context of SO I'm afraid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127627/discussion-between-ahmed-f-mostafa-and-zoltan-tamasi).